# Hadoop : Provide directory as input to MapReduce job

Tags: java, hadoop, input, mapreduce, cloudera

I'm using Cloudera Hadoop. I'm able to run simple mapreduce program where I provide a file as input to MapReduce program.

This file contains all the other files to be processed by mapper function.

But, I'm stuck at one point.

```
/folder1
  - file1.txt
  - file2.txt
  - file3.txt
```

How can I specify the input path to MapReduce program as `"/folder1"`, so that it can start processing each file inside that directory ?

Any ideas ?

**EDIT :**

1) Intiailly, I provided the inputFile.txt as input to mapreduce program. It was working perfectly.

```
>inputFile.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

2) But now, instead of giving an input file, I want to provide with an input directory as arg[0] on command line.

```
hadoop jar ABC.jar /folder1 /output
```

Comment: how are you submitting/creating the job?

Comment: Yes that works like that, what is your question?

Comment: My Question is : If I specify the directory "folder1" as input (arg[0]), which contains files to be processed, how do I capture and pass individual files to be processed to mapper function ?

Comment: @peeppeep Just set the directory as your MapReduce input.  Hadoop will process all the files in that directory.

Answer (score 13):

The Problem is  FileInputFormat doesn't read files recursively in the input path dir.

**Solution:**  Use Following code

`FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(job, true);` Before below line in your Map Reduce Code

`FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));`

You can check [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-3193) for which version it was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

you could use [FileSystem.listStatus](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listStatus%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%5B%5D%29) to get the file list from given dir, the code could be as below:

```
//get the FileSystem, you will need to initialize it properly
FileSystem fs= FileSystem.get(conf); 
//get the FileStatus list from given dir
FileStatus[] status_list = fs.listStatus(new Path(args[0]));
if(status_list != null){
    for(FileStatus status : status_list){
        //add each file to the list of inputs for the map-reduce job
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, status.getPath());
    }
}
```

Comment: after adding path how can we access it in map job? will it directly return content of files?

Answer (score 1):

you can use hdfs [wildcards](http://blog.zaloni.com/using-globs-and-wildcards-with-mapreduce) in order to provide multiple files

so, the solution :

```
hadoop jar ABC.jar /folder1/* /output
```

or

```
hadoop jar ABC.jar /folder1/*.txt /output
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [MultipleInputs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/MultipleInputs.html) class.

```
MultipleInputs. addInputPath(Job job, Path path, Class<? extends InputFormat> 
inputFormatClass, Class<? extends Mapper> mapperClass)
```

Have a look at working [code](http://dailyhadoopsoup.blogspot.in/2014/01/mutiple-input-files-in-mapreduce-easy.html)