# processing result of hdfs command output

Tags: hadoop, awk, sed

It is probably a question about stream processing. But I am not able to find a elegant solution using awk.
I am running a m/r job scheduled to run once a day. But there can be multiple HDFS directories on which it needs to run. For example, 3 input directories were uploaded to HDFS for the day, so 3 m/r jobs one for each directory needs to run.

So I need a solution, where i can extract filenames from the results of:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/xxx/17-03-15*
```

Then iterate over the filenames, launching one m/r job for each file.

Thanks

Comment: can you elaborate your question.

Answer (score 0):

Browsing more on the issue, I found Hadoop provides a configuration settings for this issue. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094366/hadoop-provide-directory-as-input-to-mapreduce-job) are details.

Also, I was just having some syntax issue and this simple awk command did, what i wanted:

```
files=`hdfs dfs -ls /user/hduser/17-03-15* | awk {'print $8'}`
```