# Hadoop NTriplesMapper (apache.jena) not working properly, Map input records=0

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, rdf, jena

Im working on implementation of PageRank algorithm, that uses Hadoop,MapReduce and RDF triples as source.

The code is pretty simple so far, main class with one job in it, followed by mapper and reducer. The input file is a .nt file full of rdf triples in it, such as :

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Anarchism> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageWikiLink> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Red_Army> .
```

Mapper is supposed to map those triples into Subject,Object pairs. For the given rdf it would be:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Anarchism> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Red_Army>
```

Reducer is supposed to group those pairs into lines containing Subject, basic PageRank (1) and list of Objects. For example:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Anarchism> 1.0 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Red_Army>,<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Joseph_Conrad>
```

I'm using hadoop 2.3.0 on windows. Apparently it is configured properly, since examples such a WordCount works on it. (edit) Tried it also under linux on hadoop 2.6.0, doesn't work any better, result is the same.

I'm executing the jar with following command:

```
hadoop jar 'C:\hwork\PageRankHadoop.jar' PageRankHadoop /in /output --all
```

With about 1500 lines long input file, execution takes about 1 minute, but it generates empty output (including _SUCCESS sic!). Apparently mapper is not working properly because in logs i can see

```
 Map-Reduce Framework
         Map input records=0
         Map output records=0
         Map output bytes=0
```

Been fiddling for 8 hours with this code today, but didint get a single output. Therefore im asking for your help, fellow coders.

I will paste some more logs from job execution below the code, it might be helpful. I have also noticed that during the execution of a job, everytime when job runs a mapper, hadoop namenode throws

```
15/04/27 21:15:59 INFO ipc.Server: Socket Reader #1 for port 9000: readAndProcess from client 127.0.0.1 threw exception [java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host] 
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.channelRead(Server.java:2502)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.access$2800(Server.java:124)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Connection.readAndProcess(Server.java:1410)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.doRead(Server.java:708)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener$Reader.doRunLoop(Server.java:582)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener$Reader.run(Server.java:553)
```

According to some articles i found its not something that would ruin my mapper, but it sure does look suspicious to me, and i have no idea why it happens.

Main class:

```
public class PageRankHadoop {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        Job job = new Job(conf, "Page Rank RDF Hadoop");
        job.setJarByClass(PageRankHadoop.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapperClass(NTriplesMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(NTriplesReducer.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(NTriplesInputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    } catch (IOException | IllegalStateException | IllegalArgumentException | InterruptedException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Error! " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }

}
```

}

```
Mapper:

   public class NTriplesMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, TripleWritable, LongWritable, Text> {

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, TripleWritable value, Context context) {
        try {
            context.write(key, new Text(value.get().getObject().getURI()));
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
            System.err.println("Mapper error: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
Reducer:

   public class NTriplesReducer extends Reducer<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    @Override
    protected void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) {
        String pageRankList = "1.0";
        for (Text value : values) {
            pageRankList += "," + value.toString();
        }
        try {
            context.write(new Text(key.toString()), new Text(pageRankList));
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
            System.err.println("Reducer error: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

Shell job execution log:
http://pastebin.com/Uf0zH20H
Syslog from hadoop\logs\userlogs:
http://pastebin.com/gNCWDsr7

edit, added loggers to the code, no exceptions has been thrown tho. Also tried to run this code under linux on hadoop 2.6.0, result is the same as on hadoop 2.3.0 under windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop Version Mismatch, or rather Jena version was the problem. One of dependencies was too old, didint realy give any sings of it but using latest version fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of possible problems with your code which I will try and highlight but it is unclear which of them might be the cause of the problem.

#### Swallowing Errors

Well the first obvious problem is that your code swallows errors:

```
catch (IOException | IllegalStateException | IllegalArgumentException | InterruptedException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    }
```

This means that any error your job throws is being silently suppressed.  At the very least you should dump the error to the console e.g.

```
catch (Throwable e) {
  System.err.println(e.getMessage());
  e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

This is the first thing I would change, if you then start seeing an error message this will give you a pointer to the actual cause of the issue.

#### Type Signatures

Secondly you are using the `Triple` type directly in your `Mapper` and `Reducer`.  The `Triple` type is a standard Java object and is not usable as a Hadoop `Writable` type.

To work with RDF data on Hadoop you need to use the [Apache Jena Elephas](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/hadoop/) libraries (which you appear to be doing in at least part of your code) and the `TripleWritable` type instead so it is unclear why Hadoop even lets your code compile/run.

#### File Read Issues

One possible issue is that you may need to explicitly specify that you want to recursively search the input path.  Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23907862/107591) try adding the following prior to setting your input path for your job:

```
FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(true);
```

#### Hadoop Version Mismatch

You are using Hadoop 2.3.0 while Elephas is built for 2.6.0 - I don't believe Elephas uses any APIs that are not backwards compatible but if all else fails you could try building the libraries yourself against your Hadoop versions per the documentation on [Using Alternative Hadoop Versions](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/hadoop/artifacts.html#using-alternative-hadoop-versions)

Comment: Thanks for your input, i will test those changes when i get back home from work. As for the Swallowing Errors part, i had dedicated logger there but i wasn't sure if the additional logger which jar i had to put into hadoop, wasn't causing the problem, i will put simple serr there. As for the Type Signatures, i will change it, it might be causing the problem. As for the File Read Issues, in shell job execution log we can read HDFS: Number of bytes read=4641, which is about right, because file is about 5kB big. as for the Hadoop Version, i will check it on 2.6.0 under linux today.

Comment: Good point on the File Read, read the wrong part of the log sorry!

Comment: Ok, i have tried it under linux on hadoop 2.6.0, there is absolutelly no difference, still 0 output. I also added that logger in catch, but there are no exceptions thrown (logger works, i tested it with invalid output path and then it did throw exception properly). That leaves us with Type Signatures, i have changed the parameters of Map method to match the input format, that is <LongWritable, TripleWritable>, but it didint give any effect. Feels like im in a dead end, any more help appriciated.

Comment: Hadoop Version Mismatch, or rather Jena version was the problem. One of dependencies was too old, didint realy give any sings of it but using latest version fixed the problem.