# How to rewrite a Java program as a Hadoop job?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

What are the *absolute* minimum modifications one must make to a Java program to render it suitable for map-reduce?

This is my Java program:

```
import java.io.*;

class evmTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String command = "evm --debug --code 7f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020101 run";
        Process proc = rt.exec(command);

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

        // read the output from the command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
        String s = null;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        // read any errors from the attempted command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

}
```

It prints output from the terminal, which renders in this way:

```
Here is the standard output of the command:

0x
Here is the standard error of the command (if any):

#### TRACE ####
PUSH32          pc=00000000 gas=10000000000 cost=3

PUSH32          pc=00000033 gas=9999999997 cost=3
Stack:
00000000  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002

PUSH32          pc=00000066 gas=9999999994 cost=3
Stack:
00000000  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
00000001  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002

ADD             pc=00000099 gas=9999999991 cost=3
Stack:
00000000  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
00000001  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
00000002  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002

ADD             pc=00000100 gas=9999999988 cost=3
Stack:
00000000  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004
00000001  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002

STOP            pc=00000101 gas=9999999985 cost=0
Stack:
00000000  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006

#### LOGS ####
```

This is, of course, one of the simplest map-reduce jobs, from the Apache examples:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

My question is- what the the most simple way to map-reducify the Java program I shared at the top of this post?

---

**UPDATE**

Ran it with this command:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.8.1.jar -D mapreduce.job.reduces=0 -input /input_0 -output /steaming-output -mapper ./mapper.sh
```

Resulted in this error:

[image]

Started running into problems here:

```
17/09/26 03:26:56 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1506277206531_0004_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
```

Additional information from the server:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't worry about "best" - get one to work and then refactor.

Comment: but then- what I'm really trying to ask is- what are the *absolute* minimum components a hadoop job needs to execute?

Comment: I echo what @duffymo said.  Get something to work first.  Then try to shrink it, one step at a time.

Comment: I've done that, I made the wordcount thing work- but now I want to do something with calling a command on the terminal in the host machine- do you know how is the simplest way I can do that in the way I demonstrate in the OP?

Comment: What data feeds into the command? Hadoop is going to distribute data across a cluster, so your process is going to be fed data from somewhere like HDFS or HBase or whatever. If your Proc object is expecting something to be on the filesystem under the hood, perhaps you could get that data from the Map(...) function, burn it to local temp file or something then run your proc. Need more info on what data is involved.

Comment: finally it's going to be a bunch of files that contain data like this `7f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020101` as you see in the OP under the variable `String command`

Comment: Are these files in HDFS?

Comment: yes, eventually I'll put them in `hdfs` but I was thinking for this first time it would be another layer of complexity, before I've even mastered how to work with map and reduce- I mean, to read a file into a program from hdfs and so on

Comment: The thing is Map Reduce (speciically MAP) has to read data from somewhere like HDFS, HBASE etc. So if you put all your files in HDFS, then use something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094366/hadoop-provide-directory-as-input-to-mapreduce-job to read them all in, you could probably run your command on what comes into the Map function as a file

Comment: remember that Hadoop distributes a process along with the data, not just a process alone.

Comment: ok cool so then, what if I put `7f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000‌​0000027f000000000000‌​00000000000000000000‌​00000000000000000000‌​0000000000027f000000‌​00000000000000000000‌​00000000000000000000‌​00000000000000000201‌​01` as a file in hdfs, and then read that in during the execution, and then collect the results of it being executed on the console as the final step- something like this?

Comment: you could read the console like you do in your code within the Map function itself, and then perhaps Reduce on some information you get out of it. You might have to get the file from HDFS, burn it to a local tmp file, then run teh command on the tmp file (all within MAP), but I'm not sure because I'm still confused about what this giant weird string thing is you are working with in the command you are executing that I am not familiar with

Comment: I think you want **Hadoop Streaming**, which will run a Shell command (or any language), and gather it's inputs and outputs. No need to write any Java code at all

Comment: @cricket_007 man that's awesome- thank you! do you know how `evm --debug --code 7f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020101 run` would look like as a streaming job?

Comment: It requires you to install this `evm` program on all the NodeManagers.

Comment: I've installed it on all the nodes

Comment: @cricket_007 the thing that's tripping me up is that- I don't know how the `mapper` and the `reducer` should be configured for such an execution as I have

Comment: Okay, well, I don't really see a point of running on Hadoop since it's a single job processing no distributed data, but here is a [WordCount Example in Bash](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140706111754-176301000-hadoop-streaming-example-job-using-bash/) and [Reasons you don't need Hadoop](https://aadrake.com/command-line-tools-can-be-235x-faster-than-your-hadoop-cluster.html)

Comment: my idea is that the code component such as this `7f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000027f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020101` will be mappable, since eventually I'll have millions of them, and then reduction phase can be the output of the command, i.e.- aggregating based on these "opcodes", such as `ADD`, `STOP`, `PUSH32` and so on, even maybe reducing snapshots of the stack like `000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002`, do you think that would work?

Comment: As pointed out previously, your big long random number means nothing to us. Let's call it `fish`. Sure, you can store `hdfs://fish.txt`, and read it into any program, but if that file is smaller than your average laptop memory, say 8Gb, or even an HDD, maybe 1Tb, then not much reason to try to stick it into hadoop. Plus, you have not shown the data input format and can your `evm` program even read HDFS blocks or from standard input? `fish` is not read as one single file

Comment: yeah but in my mind there will be a school of fish, maybe 1,000,000 small fishes, and I'd like to read them all in- and use them as input to the `evm` command. is that suitable for hadoop?

Comment: Probably. I just did a small test printing that one line 10billion times on my laptop and it's going over 8Gb at the moment

Comment: yes but that one is quite a trivial example- eventually the millions will contain "real" data on the order of this here: https://etherscan.io/address/0x41f274c0023f83391de4e0733c609df5a124c3d4#code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is not an attempt to give you a solution, but a push in the direction you should be going.

As stated, to *get something to work first*.

Let's assume you have some file like this placed at `hdfs:///input/codes.txt`

```
7f0000000002812
7f000000000281a
7f000000000281b
7f000000000281c
```

The very "simple" WordCount code actually works with this data! But, obviously you don't need to be counting anything and you don't even need a reducer. You have a map-only job that will start something like this.

```
private final Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String command = "evm --debug --code " + value.toString() + " run";
    Process proc = rt.exec(command);

    context.write( ... some_key, some_value ...);
}
```

However, you really don't need Java at all. You have a shell command, so you can use Hadoop Streaming to just run it and "stream" the code from HDFS into `stdin` for your script.

That mapper would look like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
### mapper.sh

while read code; do
   evm --debug --code $code run
done
```

You can even test that code **locally** without Hadoop (which you should try anyway to do a benchmark if you actually require the overhead of Hadoop)

```
mapper.sh < codes.txt
```

Up to you, which option works best... For the minimalist, Hadoop streaming looks simpler.

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming*.jar \
    -D mapreduce.job.reduces=0 \
    -input /input \
    -output /tmp/steaming-output \
    -mapper ~/mapper.sh
```

Also worth mentioning - Any standard output / standard error will be collected into the YARN Application logs, not necessarily back into HDFS.

Comment: man I gave it a shot, but I ended up with the error that I posted as an update to the OP- nevertheless- this is certainly an excellent thrust in the right direction and I really appreciate it- I'm sure it'll all make more sense to me tomorrow when I look at it after a bit of sleep! :)

Comment: At the bottom of the YARN UI, you can see a link for "logs". From there, you can check the stderr

Comment: is the yarn ui something I can visit over the web? one of the ports associated with a node?

Comment: yeah, I think I know what you mean, but when I click thru to the logs it just yields a 404 error(or anyway some kind of error), maybe it's that I didn't correctly configure a place for those logs to live online?

Comment: It's likely. Using the Hortonworks sandbox or Cloudera quickstart packages have all that configured for you, by the way. No need to struggle setting up plain Hadoop

Comment: does that `mapper.sh` program need to live on every node?

Comment: so with this here `evm --debug --code $code run`, how does it know how to evaluate `$code`? or- that was just a place holder?

Comment: `while read code; do` will read a line of input from `stdin` and assign it to the `code` variable

Comment: Feel free to remove the while loop and test the same mapper on a single value